# cron - How many times the cron job will run when given aterisk(*) on all positions

Tags: cron, scheduled-task, automation, service

If we define a cron job with `* * * * * /some/task/to/perform`, how many times the job will executed in 60 seconds?

Comment: Did you read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)? Cause your answer is right there..

Comment: I am new in linux world and man pages are hard for me to understand. And I asked this question because I was not able to find satisfiable answer anywhere.

Comment: The provided duplicate question has no answer that clarifies how many times a cron job run in 60 seconds for all *.

Comment: @KashyapKansara Sure it does. "Every minute of every day of every week of every month, that command runs." Every minute means your command will be run once every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron job runs every minute.

Unix cron is limited to minutes. If you want faster cronjob execution see [How can I schedule a cron job that runs every 10 seconds in linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/246044/how-can-i-schedule-a-cron-job-that-runs-every-10-seconds-in-linux/586332)